# datepicker doesn't appear inside my modal using an editor template

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

I have a text field with a date picker attached that won't appear when you click on it. I have tried placing the JS below to either file to see if it would show it. I have had a look at some other solution and none seem to be working.

When I click on the field and loom at the inspector there is nothing that even so much as looks like the datepicker, making me believe its not getting initialized.

Can someone look at my code and see if anything looks obvious, thanks!

My View:

```html
 <div class="col-sm-5">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.Lead.DOB, new { @class = "control-label" })
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-7 ">
                <div class="input-group">
                    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Lead.DOB)
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.Lead.DOB)
            </div>
```

Editor Template:

```html
@model Nullable<DateTime>

@{
    DateTime dt = Model ?? DateTime.Now;
    var dateString = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    
    <div class="input-group">
        @Html.TextBox("dobTextBox", dateString, new { @id="dobDatepicker", @class = "form-control datepicker" })
        <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-calendar addonDate calendarControl" title="Click to display a date-picker"></span>
    </div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
        

            $("#dobDatepicker").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true
            });

        });

    </script>
}
```

Comment: Do you have multiple datepicker textbox on your view ?

Comment: There are lot of partial view within the main view but this particular one is a partial view with a modal and its the only texbox field with a datepicker in that partial view

Comment: If there's other datepicker in your view only the first works ?

Comment: nope other two work just fine

Comment: Mmh maybe try to change id by class. instead `#dobDatepicker` use `.dobDatepicker` and in your textbox use `class="dobDatepicker"`.

Comment: No luck either but look at the result I got in the inspector

Comment: <input class="form-control datepicker hasDatepicker" id="ViewOptions_DateFrom" name="ViewOptions.DateFrom" placeholder="Date From..." type="text" value="27/12/2016">

Comment: The class I added didn't appear

Comment: The better way is to use only one class for datepicker. You can create a line at the end of your main view and write this : `$(".datepicker").datepicker()`

Comment: I am using jquery.validate js

Comment: already have the datepicker class setup with properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript call to the datepicker has to be outside the editor, in the view calling the editor, my main issue was that using the EditorFor helper was auto setting the id name of the input so I just checked what it was in the inspector and now it works:D